# Python :Special characters only seen when reading a file generated from unity

Tags: python-3.x, unity-game-engine, text

I am reading a file from python, this file is generated from unity, the problem is when I read the text from python am getting special characters that does not exist in the file 
This is what the file look like when I open it in the desktop:

```
il tien en son bec un fromage
```

This is what the file looks lile when open it from python 3.6

```
ï»؟il tien en son bec un fromage
```

This is the code from python:

```
path = ('C:\\Users\\HP\\Documents\\test.txt')
with open(path,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f :
        print(line)
        test = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        print(test)
```

And this is the code from unity:

```
    public void Save (){
            string Ph = Phrase.text;
            if (File.Exists ("C://Users//HP//Documents//test.txt")) {
                File.Delete ("C://Users//HP//Documents//test.txt");
                StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter ("C://Users//HP//Documents//test.txt", true, Encoding.UTF8);

                    UTF8Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding ();
                    byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes (Ph);
                    file.WriteLine (Ph);
}
```

This is so confusing

**UPDATE:**

NOW adding  encoding="utf-8-sig" solved the problem in case this would help anyone

Comment: these are most probably the UTF8-BOM marker bytes.  Use `encoding="utf-8")` when opening it with python - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: @alvits I need the file to be UT8 encoded

Comment: @PatrickArtner even if the file does not contain special characters ?

Comment: Its a special marker prepended to a file if stores as UTF8 with bom. Other programs read these first bytes, and "see" that the file is UTF8. So yes.

Comment: So how can I get rid of it

Comment: did you try `with open(path,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:` ?

Comment: Yes that's just what I was trying, it is actually no longer with` print(line)` but when i add this line` test = nltk.word_tokenize(line)
        print(test) ` am getting `['\ufeffil', 'tien', 'en', 'son', 'bec', 'un', 'fromage']` which does not suppose to be like that :/

Comment: If that's what you tried and it didn't work, why is your question not including that?

Comment: Because it did not work !! I'll edit the post

Comment: *`NOW adding encoding="utf-8-sig" solved the problem`* That's answer. Post it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the encoding to encoding="utf-8-sig" saved the problem